# residuals in R using auto.arima and forecast package

Tags: r, regression, prediction, lm, forecasting

I am fitting a model using the `auto.arima` function in package `forecast`. I get a model that is AR(1), for example. I then extract residuals from this model. How does this generate the same number of residuals as the original vector? If this is an AR(1) model then the number of residuals should be 1 less than the dimensionality of the original time series. What am I missing?

Example:

```
require(forecast)
arprocess = as.numeric(arima.sim(model = list(ar=.5), n=100))
#auto.arima(arprocess, d=0, D=0, ic="bic", stationary=T)
#  Series: arprocess 
#  ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean     

#  Coefficients:
#          ar1
#       0.5198
# s.e.  0.0867

# sigma^2 estimated as 1.403:  log likelihood=-158.99
# AIC=321.97   AICc=322.1   BIC=327.18
r = resid(auto.arima(arprocess, d=0, D=0, ic="bic", stationary=T))
> length(r)
  [1] 100
```

Update: Digging into the code of `auto.arima`, I see that it uses `Arima` which in turn uses `stats:::arima`. Therefore the question is really how does `stats:::arima` compute residuals for the very first observation?

Comment: your model is `ARIMA(1,0,1) with zero mean` not the ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean. You need to set `max.q=0` to get ARIMA(1,0,0)

Comment: can you explain why you believe this to be the case? regardless the question remains the same even if it's `ARIMA(1,0,1)`.

Comment: Yes, it is still the same. I am going thru that.

Comment: I checked the residuals for ARMA (1,0,0) and found that they are correctly computed for period 2 to 100 (y(t)-b*y(t-1)). But, I couldn't figure how it computes the residual for period 1. However, I think (in R) the length of residuals are usually kept as same as observation (as mentioned in p.5  [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FitARMA/FitARMA.pdf)). The focus, I think, should be on how it computes the residuals for the first period,  in case of ARMA(1,0,0).

Comment: Agreed. I suspect that it simply takes the value at `t=-1` to be equal to 0. Would be nice if the package author commented on this.

Comment: I don't think it sets the value to be 0 for t=1; I tried using mean, median, last observations, and so on but doesn't match; the author of package is  in SO so you might hear from him.

Comment: Yes I just tried this as well, I was incorrect about that 0 thing. Let's hope he chimes in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The residuals are the actual values minus the fitted values. For the first observation, the fitted value is the estimated mean of the process. For subsequent observations, the fitted value is $\phi$ times the previous observation, assuming an AR(1) process had been estimated.

Comment: Can you please explain the rationale of using estimated mean of the process for the first observation?Is that included in documentation?

Comment: @RobHyndman: Thanks, we suspected this was the case but both made mistakes when verifying I guess. Appreciate your help.

Comment: A fitted value is the best predictor given all previous information. For the first observation, there is no previous information. So for a stationary process, the best predictor is the mean of the process.

Comment: @RobHyndman do you refer to `auto::arima` here or this logic applies to `stats::arima` as well? I read OP's question, but I just wanted to confirm... thanks a lot!

Comment: @stucash Both. `forecast::auto.arima` calls `stats::arima` to do most of the work.

Comment: this is a bit unfair sorry OP :P @RobHyndman could you kindly take a look at this `auto:arima` [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032147/meaning-of-stationary-true-in-auto-arima-function) that I just raised? thanks very much