# meaning of stationary=TRUE in auto.arima function

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast

I have this data which is residual series obtained from predicted values and observations. original series was a random walk with a very small drift(mean=0.0025).

```
err <- ts(c(0.6100, 1.3500, 1.0300, 0.9600, 1.1100, 0.8350 , 0.8800 , 1.0600 , 1.3800 , 1.6200,  1.5800 , 1.2800 , 1.3000 , 1.4300 , 2.1500 , 1.9100 , 1.8300 , 1.9500  ,1.9999, 1.8500 , 1.5500 , 1.9800  ,1.7044  ,1.8593 , 1.9900 , 2.0400, 1.8950,  2.0100 , 1.6900 , 2.1800 ,2.2150,  2.1293 , 2.1000 , 2.1200 , 2.0500 , 1.9000,  1.8350, 1.9000 ,1.9500 , 1.7800 , 1.5950,  1.8500 , 1.8400,  1.5800, 1.6100 , 1.7200 , 1.8500 , 1.6700,  1.8050,  1.9400,  1.5000 , 1.3100 , 1.4864,  1.2400 , 0.9300 , 1.1400, -0.6100, -0.4300 ,-0.4700 ,-0.3450), frequency = 7, start = c(23, 1), end = c(31, 4))
```

and I know this residual series has some seriel correlations and can be modeled by `ARIMA`.

```
acf(err[1:length(err)]);pacf(err[1:length(err)])
# x axis starts with zero.
# showing only integer lags here, same plot as full seasonal periods. 
# shows it typically can be fitted by a MA model.
```

[image]

I have attempted following fittings:

```
library(forecast)

m1 <- auto.arima(err, stationary=T, allowmean=T)
#output
# ARIMA(2,0,0) with zero mean 

# Coefficients:

#         ar1     ar2
#      0.7495  0.2254
# s.e.  0.1301  0.1306

# sigma^2 estimated as 0.104:  log likelihood=-17.65
# AIC=41.29   AICc=41.72   BIC=47.58

m2 <- auto.arima(err, allowmean=T)
# output
# ARIMA(0,2,2) 

# Coefficients:
#          ma1     ma2
#      -1.3053  0.3850
# s.e.   0.1456  0.1526

# sigma^2 estimated as 0.1043:  log likelihood=-16.97
# AIC=39.94   AICc=40.38   BIC=46.12
```

if we refer to `auto.arima`'s help page we see that:

> stationary:    If TRUE, restricts search to stationary models.

From the `acf` and `pacf` of `err` we can see that it is to be fitted by an `MA` model rather than `AR`, why does `auto.arima` give me an `AR` fit?

My understanding is that both `m1` and `m2` should be stationary, then 
what's the purpose of this `stationary` argument?

it's even more interesting now, if we plot the roots of these two models:

[image: M1]
[image: M2]

the model when `stationary=T` (m1) is less stationary than `m2` if we look at the roots plot, although m1$residuals is white noise.

Comment: my hunch is I missed some very obvious fundamental fact when I am fitting a model...

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the first question, but regarding the second, `auto.arima()` can actually generate non-stationary models to fit the given time series. The 'i' stands for integrated, meaning it can use integration. You can transform most (all?) non-stationary models by taking the difference (diff) of each observation from the previous (much like a derivative in calculus), and then transform it back to the original time-series by integrating.

So, if you don't want to let `auto-arima()` generate non-stationary models, then you use the `stationary` argument, basically limiting it finding a fit using the simpler ARMA models.

Comment: good point, I missed the 'I' part which is obvious in `m2`. The original series was non-stationary that's why it produced an integrated model. I guess if I do `stationary=T` then it'll fit `ARMA` instead. i.e. completely forget about the `I` part. thanks.